# Azure Swap Deployment Slot Sticky Settings Not Working

Tags: azure, deployment

I have configured a production and staging slot in Azure, with each slot using it's own SQL Azure database.

The connection string for each is configured to be "sticky".

[image]

However when I go to swap the production slot (destination) with the staging slot (source) I get the following warnings.

[image]

The informative message is telling me that the the connection string from staging will overwrite the production one. Additionally the earlier warning is telling me that the DefaultConnection settings does not exist in production - BUT it does and it is also sticky.

Finally the fist two warnings are complaining about connection strings missing from both staging and production - these were indeed deleted from both as no longer required. But what are they listed as missing - what is the source of truth?

Am I missing something?

This [MSDN question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/a7dbcafe-7feb-436a-be8a-93d36d9b2803/can-i-have-a-web-app-with-a-staging-slot-where-the-slot-uses-a-different-connection-string-to?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview&prof=required) might be useful to follow

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I still don't know why the warnings are occurring, they would appear to be nonsense - if I go ahead and swap the slots I get what I expect - everything but the connection strings swap. Production still points to the production database and staging still points to the staging database.